# Forced ranking macro excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, ranking

[image]

I have the setup as shown in the image above.

Logic of the macro is if I enter a number `1` in cell `B5` or in empty cell in `Range("B2:B26")` then the output would be in this format:

```
B2 3
B3 4
B4 2
B5 1
```

Now it gives me that output but there are certain drawbacks e.g.

if I provide input `8` to the same cell then it will still increment the ranks. I incorporated a match check to see if that value is there or not but it doesn't seem to work Any help would be appreciated.

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

            Dim KeyCells As Range
            Dim i As Long, Cel As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, j As Long, found As Boolean
            Set sht1 = Sheet1

        Set KeyCells = sht1.Range("B2:C26")
        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Column = 2 Then

            For i = 2 To 26
                If sht1.Range("B" & i) <> Empty And sht1.Range("B" & i).Value >= Target.Value And i <> Target.Row Then
                        sht1.Range("B" & i).Value = sht1.Range("B" & i).Value + 1
                Else: End If
            Next i
            Else: End If


        If Target.Column = 3 Then

            For i = 2 To 26
                If sht1.Range("C" & i) <> Empty And sht1.Range("C" & i).Value >= Target.Value And i <> Target.Row Then
                        sht1.Range("C" & i).Value = sht1.Range("C" & i).Value + 1
                Else: End If
            Next i


        Else: End If


        Else: End If
        Call CreateDataLabels
        Target.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am kind of confused. If you type `1` in `B5` then what should happen? How did you get `4` in `B3`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout if you will remove this part `found = False
        For i = 2 To 26
            If sht1.Range("B" & i) <> Empty And sht1.Range("B" & i).Value = Target.Value And i <> Target.Row Then
                    found = True
            Else: End If
        Next i` you will get it.

Comment: Can you forget the code and explain the logic? :)

Comment: Yeah sure logic is I have 1-25 skills and I want to force ranking such that I cannot select the same number twice.  If I have 1, 2, 3, 4… and I add a new 3 then 3 becomes 4, 4 becomes 5 and so on.

Comment: So if you add say `8` in the above scenario (you already have 1,2,3) then should 8 remain as it is or should it become 4?

Comment: As it is because that's not a duplicate.

Comment: I think, it is pretty simple then :) Let me see what I can come up with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have not extensively tested it

```
Option Explicit

Dim rng As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   
    Dim oldVal As Long, i as Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set rng = Range("B2:B26")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        oldVal = Target.Value

        If NumExists(oldVal, Target.Row) = True Then
            For i = 2 To 26
                If i <> Target.Row And Range("B" & i).Value >= oldVal Then _
                Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i) + 1
            Next i
        End If
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub

Function NumExists(n As Long, r As Long) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To 26
        If Range("B" & i) = n And r <> i Then
            NumExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Let me test it Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: I think this `If NumExists(oldVal, Target.Row) = True Then` should be `If NumExists(oldVal, Target.Row) = False Then` right ?

Comment: Because if number doesn't exists then it shouldn't increment it by entering the loop :)

Comment: Yeah doesn't work quite because it's incrementing the `Target.Value` as well it should not touch the Target cell . Please run the edited code in the answer it will help you understand and I am also trying to do the same for column C.

Comment: But it will change the target value. That is what you mentioned in the comments. If the user enters 1 in B5, since the number already exists, it will change to 4

Comment: Check the updated code. Is that what you are trying?

Comment: You may have to refresh the page

Comment: Glad it is all sorted out

Answer (score 1):

**edited** to remove "helper" values

**edited** to add functionality for column C as well

Being Siddharth Rout's answer the solution, and having the OP's not asked for anything more, I'd propose the following as an alternative option to possibly be discussed if worth considering

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim oldVal As Long
    Dim wrkRng As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo EndThis

    If Continue(target, Range("B2:C26").Cells, oldVal, wrkRng) Then '<== here you set "B2:C26" as the "sensitive" range 
        With wrkRng
            .Offset(, 2).Value = .Value
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]<>"""",RC[2]+IF(and(RC[2]>=" & oldVal & ",ROW(RC)<>" & target.Row & "),1,0),"""")"
            .Value = .Value
            .Offset(, 2).ClearContents
        End With
    End If

EndThis:
    If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Function Continue(target As Range, rng As Range, oldVal As Long, wrkRng As Range) As Boolean
    If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Not IsEmpty(target) Then ' if cell has not been cancelled
            Set wrkRng = Intersect(target.EntireColumn, rng)
            If Not wrkRng Is Nothing Then
                oldVal = target.Value
                Continue = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wrkRng, oldVal) > 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

as compared to Siddharth Rout's solution, it enhances the following:

- more (complete?) testing as if to go on with `rng` processing

  in previous solution

  - if you cancelled a cell in `rng` it'd add 1's in all `rng` cells
  - if you pasted values in more then one `rng` cells it'd throw an error
- no use of cells iteration, both for `oldVal` counting purposes and for ranking updating

Comment: This works good and has advantages too but why do I get some numbers in column D when I enter it in B ?

Comment: my code uses a "helper" column (`Offset(, 2).Value = .Value`) which is two columns away from column "B" (i.e. column "D"). just forgot to delete "helper" column values. see edited answer: now there remain no "helper" values in column "D". If you need column "D" to be filled with relevant data, then change each `Offset(, 2)` occurrence with a different column offset as to reach a "free" column

Comment: okay but I also want to implement the same logic for column C as well like you did for column B

Comment: se edited code. I could have changed it a little less then I actually have but I preferred to keep it as optimized as I could